# Reading RFID tags with Arduino IDE, not using Arduino

Tags: arduino-ide, rfid

I am completely new to this technology, but I'm hoping to build a fairly simple program through the Arduino IDE that takes the serial numbers of RFID cards read through my ID-20LA Innovations RFID reader and send those serial numbers to an API endpoint all through the IDE (as in without using a physical Arduino).

Is this possible? Are there any tutorials out there that walk through a stripped down version of this? I don't know where to start code wise, and all tutorials I've found use physical Arduinos to accomplish this.

Comment: Arduino ide can't run the program for you. You can create your program in any language and run it on your PC it just need to communicate over serial. Python, nodejs and so on....  You can used arduino ide's Serial monitor to see the output from the reader though.

Comment: Like @Molda said, the Arduino IDE can't run programs without a physical Arduino. You could, however, use something like Processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**
NO

**Long Answer:**

Option 1:
 Use a USB RFID reader and create a basic processing/python/ app to read from the USB RFID reader and post it where ever you want it to

Option 2:
Use the arduino to read from the ID-20LA and send the data via UART to your computer and then create a windows app using processing/python/ to send it to your API endpoint

Option 3: 
Use the arduino YUN to read from the ID-20LA and then create a basic python program to run on the YUN itself. Such that it will read data from the atmel microcontroller (on the YUN) and post it to your API endpoint. This is a much cleaner yet slightly more expensive way of doing this.